# What's the purpose of RAMEOS relay?

Tags: ram, exchange, bancor

EOS.IO formulas for converting EOS to RAM and viceversa imply that the quantity

[RAM reserve]x[EOS reserve in connector] remains constant.

It was very complicated to read this from the code!

However, it looks like it would be very simple to implement the conversion EOS/RAM directly from that formula.

Why do we need a relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. no need to go through the relay if you don't sell or buy the relay token (RAMEOS) directly.
The formula can be changed to:

> amount_from / (balance_from + amount_from) * balance_to

see this patch: https://github.com/bancorprotocol/eos/commit/de4cae5ebc2a0ee5b40f81241bf5842519cd0e9c

(it also includes a fix for buyrambytes inaccuracies - see convert_quick_inv)